Extracting sounds from Conflict Global Storm SCHs
What is .sch from Conflict Global Storm and are there programs that can handle this file format, and what is the memory address for the sound function?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JNReusKPHY0lBfr1ITNAQ8jd8wVHArv3/view?usp=sharing
